# Make javascript work with decimals places

Tags: javascript, decimal

I have this script, which add a button value to the result, when the button is pressed. The function is working exactly, as it should, but i need to make i work with decimal values like:
1,00245

Here is the code:

```
 <html>
        <head>


        <script>
        function pushButton(buttonValue) {
             if (buttonValue == 'C') {
                  document.getElementById('screen').value = '0';
             }
             else {//this is where most changes occured
                    var x= document.getElementById('screen').value 
                    x =parseInt(x)+ parseInt(buttonValue);
                    document.getElementById('screen').value=x;
             }
        }
        function calculate(equation) {
             var answer = eval(equation);
             document.getElementById('screen').value = answer;
        }

        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <table class="calc" cellpadding=10>
        <tr><td colspan=3><input class="calc" id="screen" value='0'type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=1 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=2 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=3 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=4 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=5 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=6 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=7 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=8 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value=9 onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='C' onclick="pushButton(this.value);"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I've read the question a few times, and it is not at all clear what is being asked.  Reading over the code, I see at least one function, `calculate` which is not invoked here.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

```
x =parseInt(x) + parseInt(buttonValue);
```

This is flattening your input `x` to an integer, when you want a float.

Comment: It almost working.. But when i for example set the value to 1.2, it displays 2.4 when pressed twice, but when pressed 3 times it displays: 3.5999999999999996, and not 2.6 as it should?

Comment: That's a floating point error and is inherent to the language, sadly.

Comment: Too bad. Is there a simple wat to limit the result to 5 decimals?